# Is paying for ex-staff's silence a legal use of campaign funds?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, law, campaign-finance

The Trump administration reportedly [requires outgoing staff members to sign NDAs (NYT)](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/14/us/politics/omarosa-trump-campaign-arbitration-case.html).<sup>1,2</sup> Also reported, these agreements provide the staff member a [$15,000 per month payment (WaPo)](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/everyone-signed-one-trump-is-aggressive-in-his-use-of-nondisclosure-agreements-even-in-government/2018/08/13/9d0315ba-9f15-11e8-93e3-24d1703d2a7a_story.html) for their silence. Lastly, the agreements are variously made with Trump for President, the RNC, or some other PAC-name I can't remember.<sup>3</sup>

Consider for this question such an NDA signed with Trump for President. I heard a talking head today (recall is failing me!) off-handedly mention that it would certainly be a campaign finance violation. **Would it be illegal--specifically as a matter of campaign finance--for a campaign to pay for an outgoing staff member's silence?**

---

<sup>1 - whether or not such an agreement would be upheld is not my interest here. *Cf.* [...experts say she might prevail in court (WaPo)](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/politics/wp/2018/08/14/trump-accused-omarosa-of-breaching-her-nda-experts-say-she-might-prevail-in-court/)</sup>

<sup>2 - I've seen them variously described as nondisclosure, nondisparagement, or confidentiality agreements. I don't know how much of a legal difference that matters exists among those, but I also don't think that's really at issue for this question.</sup>

3 - I got this bit from reading a copy of what appeared to be one with Trump for President, and a TV report that mentioned two other entities. But I can't find those references up right now =</sup>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81677/discussion-between-nitsua60-and-guest271314).

Comment: Isn't Law SE a more appropriate venue for this question?

Answer (score 4):

Someone serving in the Trump administration is a federal employee, any classified material they have access to is already covered by relevant laws.  A NDA that covers general non-classified information they learned during their work would violate the first amendment because the US government would be a beneficiary of the NDA even though it appears that the NDA is between Trump and a (former) employee at the white house.

There is precedent for this in [McGEHEE v. CASEY](https://openjurist.org/718/f2d/1137/mcgehee-v-casey-cia) and [US v. MARCHETTI](https://openjurist.org/466/f2d/1309)

edit: As for the source of the money, if the job is from the Trump campaign I don't think it violates campaign fiance laws.  Any other source would go over the contribution limits though.

Comment: So the NDA may not be worth the paper it's written on, in terms of enforceability. But how does that answer the legality question about its funding source?

Comment: NDA in question is specific to Trump Campaign. Any document signed by Trump's Administration employees is Nondisparagement Agreement; they were included in contract on the insistence of Trump, but he was informed immediately that they are unforceable. I think this is the problem with news feeds, as they do not make clear enough distinction between the two.

Comment: Most people who have accepted payoffs or have mentioned the conditions seem to indicate it's part of the "Trump 2020" campaign, from what I've read.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  It doesn't really address campaign finance at all, which is what is being asked.